# How to get an HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> from a given String Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

So I receive a `String` that contains a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` inside how do I debunk it till I get myself a new `HashMap` from that `String`.

This is the string :

```
String s= "{Lobby1=[John, Ana], Lobby2=[Tomas, Peter]}"
```

Keep in mind the string can be longer depending on the number of entries or puts

This is what i did to get ride of the "{ }":

```
 s=s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
```

This gets me :

```
Lobby1=[John, Ana], Lobby2=[Tomas, Peter]
```

I don't know what to do now, how do I get an Arraylist and a String from that.

Comment: How could you describe in words how to extract the key and the values?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Where are you getting the `String` value from?

Comment: What you want is now _impossible_ - imagine there's a comma in those inputs, for example. Whatever gave you that string? That's the problem. I assume you had a `Map<String, List<String>>`, called `toString()` on it, and saved that somewhere, and now you want to get back to the map. You can't do that. Rewrite whatever process did the 'take the map, `toString()` it, save that' bit - that's wrong.

Comment: I m converting a HaspMap to a String and then receiving it on the other hand

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yeah that's what i did basically

Comment: *I m converting a HashMap to a String and then receiving it on the other hand.*  Perhaps that is the question you should ask.  Something like `How can I send a Java Object to a remote Java Process?`"  But using a simple String to do so is fraught with problems.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like that:

```
private static final Pattern RE = Pattern.compile("^\\s*([^=\\[\\]]+)\\s*=\\s*\\[([^\\]]*)\\]\\s*(?:,(.*))?$");

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "Lobby1=[John, Ana], Lobby2=[Tomas, Peter]";
    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.matches()) {
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
                matcher.group(2).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        map.put(name, list);
        String tail = matcher.group(3);
        if (tail == null) {
            break;
        }
        matcher = RE.matcher(tail);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```